# How is the mentioning or honoring of Ibrahim by later generations interpreted? (Shia or Sufi View)

Tags: tafseer, shiism, sufism, prophet-ibrahim

I'm a bit curious about the interpretation of the mentioning/honoring of Ibrahim (), especially from the Shi'a and/or Sufi perspective (not excluding other interpretations, but I have no access/knowledge of sources of the named sects) in context of the verses:

- The verse in surat a-Shu'ara where Ibrahim () asks Allah () to give or grant him a good reputation by later generations:

  > And grant me a reputation of honor among later generations. ([26:84](http://legacy.quran.com/26/84))
- and the verse from surat as-Saffat where Allah () has "answered" Ibrahim's supplication, saying:

  > And We left for him [favorable mention] among later generations: ([37:108](http://legacy.quran.com/37/108))

Comment: Brother what do you mean by mentioning? Do you mean the addendum to the Salawat?

Answer (score 0):

I know your Arabic is better than me but for sake of other's I'll translate them in abstract.

I'm Mentioning Shia Perspective:

**Surat a-Shu'ara (26:84) Interpretions**

**1.Tafsir Al-Qumi And Similar Hadith in Tafsir Noor Al-saghalein {1}**

> و قال علي بن إبراهيم في قوله: وَ اجْعَلْ لِي لِسانَ صِدْقٍ فِي
>   الْآخِرِينَ قال هو أمير المؤمنين ع

EN:

> From Ali Ebn Ebrahim About verse "And grant me a reputation of honor among later
>   generations. (26:84)" , It is Amir Al momenin ( = Ali ebne Abi taleb).

I should explain that in Shia every where you see "Amir Al momenin" it means "Ali ebne abi taleb, the first Imam and the forth Khalifa".

the interpretion says Ebrahim (A) has asked Allah() for لسان صدق and Allah () Accepted his request and  so Ali'ebne abi taleb (A) is in Ebrahim's generation.

So Ali ebn Abi taleb (A) ==> لسان صدق

**2. Kashf-ol-Qameh {2} also in {3} and {4} similar Hadith:**

> قَوْلُهُ تَعَالَى وَ اجْعَلْ لِي لِسانَ صِدْقٍ فِي الْآخِرِينَ‏  عَنْ
>   أَبِي عَبْدِ اللَّهِ جَعْفَرِ بْنِ مُحَمَّدٍ ع قَالَ هُوَ عَلِيُّ بْنُ
>   أَبِي طَالِبٍ عَرَضَتْ وَلَايَتُهُ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ ع فَقَالَ
>   اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْهُ مِنْ ذُرِّيَّتِي فَفَعَلَ اللَّهُ ذَلِكَ.

EN:

> About verse "And grant me a reputation of honor among later
>   generations. (26:84)" that is Ali ebn abi taleb (A). [Allah Asked
>   ebrahim] to accept supervision of ali ebn abi taleb.[he accepts and]
>   asks Allah to put Ali (A) in his generations. and Allah () did that!

**3.khesal{4} -> Middle of big Hadith:**
... َ

> ِ قَوْلِ النَّبِيِّ ص لَمَّا قَالَ لِأَمِيرِ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ ع‏ 
>   فِي قَوْلِهِ وَ اجْعَلْ لِي لِسانَ صِدْقٍ فِي الْآخِرِينَ أَرَادَ
>   بِهِ هَذِهِ الْأُمَّةَ الْفَاضِلَةَ فَأَجَابَهُ اللَّهُ وَ جَعَلَ لَهُ
>   وَ لِغَيْرِهِ مِنْ أَنْبِيَائِهِ لِسانَ صِدْقٍ فِي الْآخِرِينَ وَ هُوَ
>   عَلِيُّ بْنُ أَبِي طَالِبٍ ع وَ ذَلِكَ قَوْلُهُ عَزَّ وَ جَلَّ وَ
>   جَعَلْنا لَهُمْ لِسانَ صِدْقٍ عَلِيًّا.

...

> Translation is almost same as previous Hadith

***References:***

{1}.تفسير نور الثقلين ؛ ج‏4 ؛ 57

{2}.كشف الغمة في معرفة الأئمة (ط - القديمة) ؛ ج‏1 ؛ 320

{3}.نهج الحق و كشف الصدق ؛ 199

{4}.الصراط المستقيم إلى مستحقي التقديم ؛ ج‏1 ؛ 256

Comment: And how was لسان صدق interpreted I mean how would 'Ali () fit to this expression?

Comment: 1 question here, What does Ali (RA) have to do with any of this, he wasn't even there at the time of Ibrahim (AS). Just curious to know about it though I am sunni.

Answer (score 0):

, I can provide you with a general understanding of how the mentioning or honoring of Ibrahim (Abraham) by later generations is interpreted in Shia and Sufi perspectives. However, please note that interpretations within these groups can vary among scholars and individuals.

Shia View: In Shia Islam, Ibrahim holds a significant position as a revered prophet and a role model of faith and submission to Allah. Shia Muslims honor Ibrahim and his family, including his son Ismail (Ishmael) and his wife Hajar (Hagar). They emphasize the importance of following the righteous path of Ibrahim and his descendants, particularly the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) and his Ahl al-Bayt (household).

Shia Muslims commemorate the event of Ibrahim's willingness to sacrifice his son, known as Eid al-Adha or the Feast of Sacrifice. They view this event as a symbol of complete submission to Allah's command and as a reminder of the importance of sacrificing for the sake of Allah.

Sufi View: Sufism, a mystical branch of Islam, often places a strong emphasis on spiritual connection and inner purification. Sufis interpret the mentioning and honoring of Ibrahim as a means to reflect on his qualities of faith, devotion, and surrender to Allah. They seek to emulate Ibrahim's spiritual journey and his unwavering trust in Allah.

Sufis may engage in various practices, such as reciting Ibrahim's supplications or meditating on his story, to deepen their spiritual connection and seek inspiration from his example. They may also focus on the symbolism within Ibrahim's life, such as the concept of sacrificing one's ego and desires for the sake of Allah.

It's important to note that while these interpretations exist within Shia and Sufi perspectives, they do not represent the views of all individuals within these groups. Islam encourages Muslims to honor and respect all the prophets and messengers of Allah, including Ibrahim, as they are all considered important figures in the history of monotheism.

If you seek more specific or detailed information on the interpretations within Shia or Sufi traditions, I recommend consulting scholars or resources specialized in those areas.

May Allah bless us all with a deep understanding of His message and guide us on the path of righteousness.